Latency in receiving TCP String sent from TCPServer
I'm working on an application that requires a very responsive TCP communication across two PC (connected through direct Ethernet). I've used the code below to benchmark the responsiveness of the TCP socket (both TCP Server & TCP Client):
TCP Server
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string serverAddress = "192.168.23.88"; // Localhost
        int serverPort = 6012;

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverAddress), serverPort);
        server.Server.NoDelay = true;
        server.Start();
        Console.WriteLine($"Server started {serverAddress}:{serverPort}...");

        while (true)
        {
            var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            client.NoDelay = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected...");
            HandleClientAsync(client); // Fire and forget
        }
    }


    private static void HandleClientAsync(TcpClient client)
    {
        using (client)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[20];
            var stream = client.GetStream();

            var t1RP = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<TEST,1>");
            var t2RP = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<TEST,2>");
            var t3RP = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<TEST,3>");

            List<string> consoleList = new List<string>();
            //string tmp = "";
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead;
                try
                {
                    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error reading from client: {e.Message}");
                    foreach (var a in consoleList)
                        Console.WriteLine(a);

                    break;
                }

                stream.Write(sovRP, 0, t1RP.Length);
                stream.Write(grbRP, 0, t2RP.Length);
                stream.Write(resRP, 0, t3RP.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}

TCP Client
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string serverAddress = "192.168.23.88"; // Localhost
    int serverPort = 6012;

    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            int cycle = 5000;
            client.NoDelay = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...");
            await client.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, serverPort);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Connected to server {serverAddress}:{serverPort}");

            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            Stopwatch elapsedTime = new Stopwatch();

            var stream = client.GetStream();
            int count = 0;
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
                for (int i = 0; i < cycle; ++i)
                {
                    long responseTime = 0;
                    long grabTime = 0;
                    long resultTime = 0;
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"<SOV,1,4,>");
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    _ = stream.FlushAsync();

                    elapsedTime.Restart();
                    
                    string combined = "";
                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        combined += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        if (combined.Contains("<TEST,1>"))
                        {
                            _ = stream.FlushAsync();
                            responseTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                            combined = combined.Replace("<TEST,1>", "");
                            if (responseTime > 3)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} SOV Response Time {responseTime}");
                                responseTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                                count++;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Received from server: {response}");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        combined += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        if (combined.Contains("<TEST,2>"))
                        {
                            grabTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds - responseTime;
                            combined = combined.Replace("<TEST,2>", "");
                            if (grabTime > 3)
                            {
                                _ = stream.FlushAsync();
                                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} SOV Grab Time {grabTime}");
                                grabTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds - responseTime;
                                count++;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Received from server: {response}");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        combined += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        if (combined.Contains("<TEST,3>"))
                        {
                            resultTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds - responseTime - grabTime;
                            combined = combined.Replace("<TEST,3>", "");
                            if (resultTime > 10)
                            {
                                _ = stream.FlushAsync();
                                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} SOV Result Time {resultTime}");
                                resultTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds - responseTime - grabTime;
                                count++;
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Received from server: {response}");

                    time.Restart();
                    while (time.ElapsedMilliseconds < 50)
                    {

                    }

                    if ((i % 50) == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine($"Complete {i} Cycle");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Completed {cycle} Cycle, Exceed Count {count}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
}

I've noticed that in 5000 cycles, I will randomly get some delayed response (5ms - 20ms).

I've used WireShark to monitor the TCP stream in both Server and Client. In Server side, TCP is sent out immediately but in Client side, there's some latency:
Server Side

Client Side

Is there anything I have missing out in TCP configuration?
Thanks in advance.
Update (10th Dec 2024):
I've modified the test program slightly as per advice by Rowan Smith, the updated TCP Client code is as below:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //string serverAddress = "192.168.23.88"; // Localhost
    string serverAddress = "192.168.23.188"; // Localhost
    int serverPort = 6012;

    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        client.NoDelay = true;
        try
        {
            int cycle = 5000;
            client.NoDelay = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to server...");
            await client.ConnectAsync(serverAddress, serverPort);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Connected to server {serverAddress}:{serverPort}");

            Stopwatch time = new Stopwatch();
            Stopwatch elapsedTime = new Stopwatch();

            var stream = client.GetStream();

            int count = 0;
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
                for (int i = 0; i < cycle; ++i)
                {
                    long responseTime = 0;
                    long grabTime = 0;
                    long resultTime = 0;
                    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{cycle};<SOV,1,4,>");
                    //stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    _ = stream.FlushAsync();
                    //Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Data sent to server");
                    elapsedTime.Restart();

                    string combined = "";
                    #region Test Single
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        combined += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} {combined}");
                        {
                            _ = stream.FlushAsync();
                            responseTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                            //combined = combined.Replace("<4,SOVRP,OK,1>", "");
                            if (responseTime > 3)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} SOV Response Time {responseTime}");
                                //Console.ReadLine();
                                responseTime = elapsedTime.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                                count++;
                            }
                            break;
                        }me.Restart();
                    while (time.ElapsedMilliseconds < 50)
                    {

                    }

                    if ((i % 50) == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine($"Complete {i} Cycle");

                    continue;
                    #endregion
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} Completed {cycle} Cycle, Exceed Count {count}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Connection closed");
}

Now TCPServer is sending 3 messages and TCPClient is receiving all 3 messages in 1 Socket.Read(). I then continue to monitor the responsiveness using WireShark and I noticed that in WireShark TCPServer side, there's an [ACK] (From TCPClient to TCPServer) in TCP Server side that causing that delay.

This [ACK] is not part of the message I sent across TCPServer / TCPClient. Any idea why is that occurs?

What did you expect? What network is in between?

I would start with a comparison to some existing protocol and library, like gRPC. I would also suggest using a length prefix, so you know how long each message is, instead of always reading 20 bytes.

BTW - In general you cannot assume what has arrived in your buffer is a complete set of UTF8 characters, unless you're only working with the ASCII subset (in which case, using the ASCII encoding would make that clearer). As such, you should heed the remarks: "If the data to be converted is available only in sequential blocks (such as data read from a stream) ... you should use the Decoder or the Encoder provided"

@Fildor I am expecting immediate response from Client once TCP message is received (Response time < 5ms)

@JonasH Yes, length preFix will be good. For testing purpose, I am setting it as 20 bytes since I know what message is coming in.

The key here is that what you are seeing in Wireshark is a reassembled PDU, not the packet on the wire.  And what you are seeing in your Console output is because of the way you are reading and writing the stream.

There are a bunch of things going on here.

SO_DELAY

You need to set SO_NODELAY on the Server side clients Socket.
You have set SO_NODELAY on the TcpListener socket, but not on the client socket that the server creates.  Every time a new client connects to the TcpListener a new Socket is created.
private static void HandleClientAsync(TcpClient client)
{
    using (client)
    {
         client.NoDelay = True;  // <---

You don't need to set it on the Server's Socket.  This has no effect as the Server Socket only handles the 3-way handshake.  This is why you had to do it on the underlying socket because TcpListener doesn't provide a native property for it as it has no effect.

The Writes:

This Code is almost certainly sending all three byte[]'s in one Network Packet:
            stream.Write(sovRP, 0, t1RP.Length);
            stream.Write(grbRP, 0, t2RP.Length);
            stream.Write(resRP, 0, t3RP.Length);

Even with SO_NODELAY enabled these will probably still hit the wire in one network packet.

Read Algorithm

Your Client Side algorithm is flawed, you need to read from the Socket and then test for the strings, if you add a ever increasing counter on the server side, you will eventually see missed messages on the client side because of the way you are reading from the stream.
Even with SO_NODELAY you absolutely still could get multiple TEST_STRING's in the same Socket.Read() result.  So your code needs to take this into consideration.
At the very least you should only read the number of bytes in each message (7 bytes).

Wireshark

Your Wireshark is set to reassemble PDUs so the times you have are wrong for the line you have the ARROW on, because what you are seeing as a packet, isn't actually a packet, it's taken from the previous packets in the capture, and generated at that time, which if you look in the trace, is packets #3265, #3266 and #3273 - Wireshark has reassembled these packets into a X11 packet and produced the output.
In Wireshark go to, Analyze > Protocols and turn off X11, or use a different port on the server side.

Thanks.  Allow me to reply each item as below:
SO_DELAY
I've added the suggested code, but unfortunately I still get delay.
I've further tested and found out that, if I set server.Server.NoDelay = true, the newly connected client will have NoDelay=true.

The Writes & Read Algorithm:
Yes you are right. I've rearrange TCPClient code and I noticed that all 3 TEST_STRING comes in the same Socket.Read() result.
